# Native String Search Algorithm's best time complexity

Tags: algorithm

When I'm studing this algorithm, I found that the best time complexity is O(n), as the book says. But why is not O(m)? I think the best condition is: pattern string successfully matches at the main string's first position, so only m comparisons are needed.

ps. n is the main string's length and m is the length of pattern string

Comment: Which book, and what exactly does it say?

Comment: "the best time complexity" presumably means "the best worst-case time complexity"

Comment: What is *native* about `Native String Search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When discussing string search algorithms, it is most often understood as having to find *all* occurrences. For example, Wikipedia has in its [String-searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Overview) article:

> The goal is to find one or more occurrences of the needle within the haystack.

This is confirmed in Wikipedia's description of the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm), where it states:

> The comparisons continue until either the beginning of P is reached (which means there is a match) or a mismatch occurs upon which the alignment is shifted forward (to the right) according to the maximum value permitted by a number of rules. The comparisons are performed again at the new alignment, and ***the process repeats*** until the alignment is shifted past the end of T, which means no further ***matches*** will be found.

And again, for the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) we find the same:

> the Knuth–Morris–Pratt string-searching algorithm (or KMP algorithm) searches for ***occurrences*** of a "word" W within a main "text string" S [...]
>
> ```
> input:
>     an array of characters, S (the text to be searched)
>     an array of characters, W (the word sought)
> output:
>     an array of integers, P (positions in S at which W is found)
>     an integer, nP (number of positions)
> ```

So even in your best case scenario the algorithm must continue the search after the initial match.

Answer (score -1):

yes when you use Bit based (approximate) you can have complexity O(n) but how can you want to find in O(m). Think your first string is a string with length 10^10 and all the characters are 'A', let pattern string "B" so how can you want find "B" in this string with O(m) that m = 1